# How To Create JPanels at runtime and show its name when user click on it

Tags: java, swing

I am creating Chess game , for this i am creating 64 JPanels using Loop. and changing background color, here is the example code that i am using to create panel and changing its background color.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for( int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            jp[i][j]=new JPanel();
            p.add(jp[i][j]);
            this.allSquares.add(jp[i][j]); // adding panel in arraylist of type Jpanel
            if(j%2==0&&i%2==0)// code to change background color of panels for chess board
            {
            jp[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
            if(j%2!=0&&i%2!=0)
            {
            jp[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

i need code to get name of the `JPanel` when user click on it in chess board

Comment: Can't just use [setName(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName-java.lang.String-) and [getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName--) inherited from [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

extend JPanel and add a name property that you want to save and read

```
   class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public final int i;
        public final int j;
        public MyPanel(int i,int j){
            super();
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }
    }
```

and

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for( int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            jp[i][j]=new MyJPanel(i,j);
            p.add(jp[i][j]);
            jp[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    MyPanel p = (MyPanel)e.getSource();
                    // p.i p.j
                }
            });
            this.allSquares.add(jp[i][j]); // adding panel in arraylist of type Jpanel
            if(j%2==0&&i%2==0)// code to change background color of panels for chess board
            {
            jp[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
            if(j%2!=0&&i%2!=0)
            {
            jp[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

and on click listener, cast panel to MyPanel

```
MyPanel p = (MyPanel)object;
String name = p.name;
```

Comment: 1) `public String name`: public access to class members breaks encapsulation principle an it's a really bad advice. 2) There's no need to subclass `JPanel`.

Comment: @dic19 but get/putClientProperty ... :-)

Comment: theoretically is way to go, you have to save unique id for those Objects, to change in your answer to get/putClientProperty

Comment: thanks @Adem for your answer , i am total newbie in java , can you please give me code for Click Listener that will work for all Panels ? or simple complete java file that will do this task.

Comment: I updated my answer. it is not perfect regarding to software principles, but it works

Comment: @Adem thank u so much , but i make this code with the help of your code , and its according to principles :) Cool thanks Man 

                    jp[i][j].setName(""+i+","+j);
               and in mousepressed event :)
                    JPanel p = (JPanel)e.getSource();
                    System.out.println(p.getName());